# is there any function to filter dataset based on rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm trying to get list of some platform from dozen of platform in dataset
[video-games-sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20LgV.png)

```
Rank Name               Platform Year Genre     Publisher NA_Sales
1    Wii Sports         Wii      2006 Sports    Nintendo  41.25
2    Super Mario Bros.  NES      1985 Platform  Nintendo  23.65
3    Mario Kart Wii     Wii      2008 Racing    Nintendo  15.65
4    Wii Sports Resort  Wii      2009 Sports    Nintendo  14.23
```

as you can see, there are various platform on `platform` column. but I just want to get list of a platform.

I have tried to drop every platform on rows. but i just think that this is not the effective way because I need to look to all of the platform and drop any unused platform

is there any function to filter it?

Comment: Hi Dimas, welcome to stack overflow. May you provide us an example of an expected  output so that we would know what you are looking for exactly

Comment: Please post your expected output based on sample input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return you a dataframe just containing the rows that has the platform "Wii" on it.

```py
df = df[df.Platform.eq("Wii")]
```

You can find more stuff on pandas documentation.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html